# Disable "Fwd" label in Gmail while forwarding mails

Tags: gmail, email-forwarding

I forward mails a lot and I don't want to reveal to the receiver that the mail is being forwarded. So each time while forwarding I end up manually removing the `Fwd:` label from the **subject** and the

`---------- Forwarded message ----------`

from the body.

Is there any way to activate labeling only when needed?

Is there any trick or workaround other than manually removing them?

Comment: that's not labeling.

Comment: Hi @Sathya, I agree. So is there any specific/one-word term to call it?

Comment: not that I know of.

Comment: I think the best way to describe it would probably be a Subject tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not a label that is a part of the subject and body that are added by almost every single email program that lets the receiver of your mail know that the email is originally from another source.

If you are truly concerned about the privacy of the original sender then you may just want to try to use copy and paste.  In the original email use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (<kbd>Cmd</kbd> on Mac) to select the entire body of the email then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy the selected content.  I would then either start a new email or simply click to forward and then in the body of the draft email once again use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select the entire body and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste the original body of content over current content.

This method along with using the forward button will leave the *"Fwd:"* in the subject line, however, it could be debated whether or not it should remain to let the receiver know that the content of the mail was not originally from you even if your hide who is the actual original author.

Comment: Hi @Bradley, I'm aware of manual Copy Paste. My question still stands. `Is there any trick or workaround other than manually removing them?`

Comment: @LakshmiNarayananGuptha no.

Comment: @LakshmiNarayananGuptha I do not know of any such workaround.  Someone may be able to develop some type of solution like that using something like Greasemonkey, but being such a unlikely used option for the majority it is unlikely to get some

Comment: This will not include attachments